# Openbravo 3 database diagram

Tags: openbravo

I'm from Brazil, and after much research on Opensource ERP's, I chose the Openbravo 3.0 to use in my company.

As I will develop new modules for use in my company, I wonder if anyone has the relationship diagram of the tables in database openbravo3.

Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the E/R diagram for the 3.0 release is not publicly available but the entity model it is on Openbravo's wiki:
 http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ERP/3.0/Developers_Guide/Reference/Entity_Model

You can also find the E/R diagram for the 2.3X releases:
 http://sourceforge.net/projects/openbravo/files/07-openbravo-other/other/
but it is quite old.

I guess that with more than 200 tables on the database such a E/R document is a bit complex to maintain and not really useful because you can always obtain it (totally or partially) with any database tool like Toad or Aqua Studio. Such database tools have an option to export from the database (or a set of tables) the corresponding E/R diagram.

From my experience, with the entity model link above and a tool to generate the necessaries E/R diagrams under-demand is more than enough to develop anything in Openbravo ERP.

Anyway you can always ask in Openbravo's forums:
 http://forge.openbravo.com/projects/openbravoerp/forum/
maybe someone just created the whole E/R diagram for the 3.0 version and wants to share it.

Regards,

Comment: And what do you mean by "not publicly available"?

Answer (score 1):

The database model of Openbravo is not a key requirement, because openbravo follows a Model Driven Development Pattern, which as a consequence creates Screens ( called Windows ) which follow the Database Model quite precisely : 
Example : 
Order lines are generated as a Subtab of the Order Window.

An other way of answering is also that the full model is actually stored in a MetaModel in openbravo itself : 
(in the UI, login as System Administrator and browse the Application Dictionary to the "Table" Window, or check the "AD_Table" Table in the database.) This is not going to directly give you the Model itself, but it is the list of tables and their relationships. And it is always up to date and consistent with the modules you installed. + It comes with additional descriptions of what is the table.
You will also easily be able to find which Table Columns are related to which Window fields.

Hope that helps,